# Ionic 5 - Change style of .range-slider in IonRange which is under #shadow-root in Safari/iOS

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, shadow-dom, ionic5

I need to change the styling of the .range-slider class to make a bigger touch area but since it is under #shadow-root  the only way I could do that was using

```
const customStyleElement = document.createElement('style');
customStyleElement.innerHTML = `.range-slider {
   height: 200px !important;
   top: 97px;
}`); 
rangeRef.current.shadowRoot.appendChild(customStyleElement);
```

This works fine for Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari or mobile iOS.

Safari Shadow Content example

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Dealing with the Shadow Dom can be very confusing some times. Would you mind adding a screenshot of how the ion-range should look like in your project? That way it'd be easier to know what's the expected end result and see how that can be achieved. Thanks! :)